# I am facing a problem in generating bubble enrichment plot using ggplot from fgsea result

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a bubble plot:

My data looks like this:

[image]

My code for the bubble plot:

```
bubble1 <- ggplot(a, aes(y = pathway, x = Condition, size = size)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = NES, size=size)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5))
```

It does not show any error but the result looks as follows:

[image]

The plot was supposed to be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Most likely the names on the Y axis are way too long to actually see anything on the graph. But it's hard to know without code or a working example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` and `y` arguments are both factors (it seems). Considering the screenshot of your data in excel, the value of `Condition` is `Tumor` for all (visible) `pathway` values. Thus specifying `Condition` as `x` variable with the same value for all your `y` variable values results in the kind of plot you show here.

To achieve a plot as the one you want to actually get, your `x` variable should be numeric, e.g. any of the columns B to F in excel.

Comment: That's not really useful. And actually not right. A numeric is not required. Check this simple example data `a <- data.frame(pathway = LETTERS[1:10], Condition = "Tumor", size = 1:10, NES = 1:10)` and you will see that you get a plot which is absolutely fine. The issue is more likely related to the long labels as noted by thehand0 in his comment, which you can check by using `pathway = vapply(LETTERS[1:10], function(x) paste(rep(x, 60), collapse = ""), FUN.VALUE = character(1))`